# What can foreground generation 2 garbage collection do that background can't?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr, .net-4.5

In [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202(v=vs.110).aspx), it is explained that the new (to .NET 4.5) [SustainedLowLatency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gclatencymode(v=vs.110).aspx) garbage collection mode prevents foreground generation 2 collections, but allows background generation 2 collections.

> SustainedLowLatency suppresses foreground generation 2 collections and performs only generation 0, 1, and background generation 2 collections. It can be used for longer periods of time, and is available for both workstation and server garbage collection.

I understand about generations, but can anyone clarify what a foreground collection can do that a background collection cannot? E.g. What memory will not get reclaimed due to this setting being applied?

What I'm trying to find out is what potential problems I may have by setting the latency mode to SustainedLowLatency.

Please note that I understand this mode should only be activated for a finite interval where responsiveness is key - this is how we are using it. I'm just trying to understand what the full implications of this setting are.

Comment: Background GC cannot stop a fire-hose problem, your app consuming memory faster than it can be collected.  Nothing pretty happens when that occurs of course.  You will have to keep an eye on the perf counters.  "Finite intervals" is the opposite of "Sustained".

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant (I was hoping you, Eric, or Jon would reply!). That's reassuring - my app doesn't claim that much memory - it just needs to be responsive (soft real-time) over a long period (a business day). I understood that Sustained in this context doesn't mean "permanently" - I think you're still only meant to use it for finite intervals, but you can use it for hours, whereas the old LowLatency setting was designed more for minutes. I'm not sure where I got that understanding though - I've been reading a lot over the last few days!